# Instant update JSP / HTML without the need to redeploy

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, intellij-idea, glassfish

Working with JSPs design / HTML is a problem because one should always redeploy the application when a change is made. Application redeployment is time consuming, it would be better if I can make some changes to JSP / HTML, refresh the browser and wholaaa !. In Idea intellij there update resource / update resources and classes is there something like this in Eclipse ? 
I am using glassfish server for my application deployment and J2EE.

Comment: HTML and JSP files can be edited at runtime and your browser refreshed to display the changes.  Only changes to a servlet source file requires you to recompile and redeploy.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you can republish your Application. It's still a little bit time consuming, but you haven't to redeploy the whole Application. Additionally it's possible to change some settings in the way, that Eclipse republishing your App automaticaly after you've saved some changes. Admitedly I don't know if this is a native Eclipse functionality or if you need a plugin for that.